# Apparently equal axios.put methods, only one works fine

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, fetch

Can someone explain the difference between those 2 syntax, and why the first does not work?

**This gives me a 401 error:**

```
const handleSubmit = () => {
axios.put(`url`, {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Token ${token}`,
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    data: data,
  })
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
  })

 };
```

**While this works perfectly:**

```
var config = {
method: "put",
maxBodyLength: Infinity,
url: "url",
headers: {
  Authorization: `Token ${token}`,
  "Content-Type": "application/json",
},
data: data,
};

const handleSubmit = () => {
axios(config)
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
  })
};
```

Comment: You pass the data in headers so that's wrong. Pass data before headers like this (URL , data , headers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first code snippet is incorrect because the headers and data properties should be passed as options to axios.put() method, not as properties of the data object. The correct syntax should be:

```
axios.put(url here, data, {
  headers: {
    Authorization: `Token ${token}`,
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  }
})
.then(function (response) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
})
```